# Hovering effect applied to hovered part of the pattern

Tags: html, css, hover

I made a div and filled it with a "red box" pattern.

[image]

I have a "blue box" pattern which i want to apply once you hover over a "red box".

[image]

But however I am getting the following result instead of the above one, that all the "red box" changes to "blue box".

[image]

I would like to change the hovered part of the pattern only to "blue box".
How can I do that?

HTML:

```
<div id="sample"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#sample {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-image:url("..\redbox.png");
}
#sample:hover {
  background-image:url("..\bluebox.png");
}
```

PS: The above images are just for illustrating the situation, the actual scene contains more complex pattern in large number. So please consider giving an answer which can be applied to any kind of pattern.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/f3589c95/

Comment: You can't change *parts* of a background image...it's not possible...even "patterns". Just like you can't hover over a *part* of a single element. I suspect you'd need an SVG or,more likely, `canvas` and javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to make a table

```css
#sample {
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;

    ;
}
#sample table tr td{
    width:10vw;
    height:10vh;
    background-color:red;
    ;
}
#sample table tr td:hover {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="sample">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I need an answer which can be applied to **Patterns**.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change just one part of a background image, it will change other parts too. You can only define only one `background-image` property per element.
That's why you can use two `div` s, one above the other. For this you can use `position` property. Set it to `relative` and `top` property to `-100vh`. This value may change according to how you use the `div` s. Make sure you set them so that the `div` s overlap.

Now, you need to get the position of cursor above that element and get the `background-position` of the "red box" that your user is hovering on and apply it to `#sample2`'s `background-position` property and place the "blue box" above the "red box".

HTML:

```
<div id="sample1"></div>
<div id="sample2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#sample1 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("..\redbox.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
#sample2:hover {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  top: -100vh;
  background-image: url("..\bluebox.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: -<redbox.png width>px -<redbox.png height>px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function hoverFunc(e) {
    var sideX = <redbox.png width>;
    var sideY = <redbox.png height>;
    var mouseX = e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop;
    var posX = mouseX - (mouseX % sideX);
    var posY = mouseY - (mouseY % sideY);
    document.getElementById("sample2").backgroundPositionX = posX + "px";
    document.getElementById("sample2").backgroundPositionY = posY + "px";
}

function outFunc(e) {
    document.getElementById("sample2").style.backgroundPositionX = "-<redbox.png width>px ";
    document.getElementById("sample2").style.backgroundPositionY = "-<redbox.png height>px";
}

document.getElementById("sample2").addEventListener("mousemove", hoverFunc, false);
document.getElementById("sample2").addEventListener("mouseout", outFunc, false);
```

Note that position of `#sample2` is taken since the cursor will hover on it as it is present above `sample1`.